# if value is in array using includes not working

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays:

```
ids = [a,b,c,d,e,f....];

savedRepods = [e,f];

  function getPoints(){
      for (var i = 0; i < savedRepods.length; i++) {
        if(ids.includes(savedRepods[i]) ) {
          console.log(savedRepods[i]);
        }
      }
  }
```

I know the value is in the array but this won't show me the value `console.log(savedRepods[i]);`

Full code:

```
  /** get saved values from the server */
  var savedRepods = <?php echo json_encode($userPostsInternal); ?> ;
  savedRepods = savedRepods.split(",");

  /** create single arrays for the values */

  var date = [],
      coords = [],
      ids = [],
      metal = [],
      plastic = [],
      paper = [],
      glass = [],
      indirizzo = [];

  /** convert to a variable ALL the other values form the server */

  var array = <?php echo $contents; ?> ;

  /** push single values into correspondent arrays */

  array.map(function(item) {
      coords.push(item.Lat + "," + item.Lng);
      ids.push(item.ID);
      date.push(item.Date);
      plastic.push(item.Plastic);
      paper.push(item.Paper);
      glass.push(item.Glass);
      metal.push(item.Metal);
  });


  /**
   * Now process the response from locationData
   */
  var locations = getPoints();

  /**
   * findLatLang
   */
  function findLatLang(location, geocoder, value) {
      /**
       * Return new Promise what resolves when 
       * the geocoder is successfull
       * and push in the array of promises
       */
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          /** Do geocoder */
          geocoder.geocode({
              'location': location
          }, function(results, status) {
              /**
               * If geocoder is Ok
               */
              if (status === 'OK') {
                  /**
                   * When the geocoder is successfull located
                   * resolve the promise and send the response of formate address
                   */
                  resolve([results[0].formatted_address, value]);
              } else {
                  /**
                   * Reject the promise
                   */
                  reject(new Error('Couldnt\'t find the location ' + location));
              }
          })
      })
  }

  /**
   * processData 
   * return an array of promises
   */
  function getPoints(){
      /**
       * Declare a variable of promises that have a geocoder
       */
      let locationData = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < savedRepods.length; i++) {

        if(ids.includes(savedRepods[i]) ) {

          console.log(savedRepods[i]);

          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
          var latlngStr = coords[a].split(',', 2);
          var latlng = {
              lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]),
              lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])
          };

          /**
           * Push geocoder in array of locationdata
           * Send the geocoder object on function and send the map
           */
          locationData.push(findLatLang(latlng, geocoder, a))
        }
      }

      /** return array of promises */
      return locationData;
  }

  Promise.all(locations)
    .then(function(returnVals){
    indirizzo = returnVals;
    doAddress(indirizzo)
  });

  var usedId = [],
      usedMetal = [],
      usedGlass = [],
      usedPaper = [],
      usedLocation = [],
      usedPlastic = [];


      const data = [];

  function doAddress(indirizzo) {
    indirizzo.forEach(function(item){
      var a = item[1];
      var location = item[0];

      let newObj = {};
      newObj.idValue = ids[a];
      newObj.addressValue = location;
      newObj.metalValue = metal[a];
      newObj.glassValue = glass[a];
      newObj.plasticValue = plastic[a];
      newObj.paperValue = paper[a];
      data.push(newObj);

      $("#eachValue ul").append("<li class='list-group-item'>repod id= " + ids[a] + "<br> Indirizzo = " + location + "<br> Metallo = " + metal[a] + ", <br> Plastica = " + plastic[a] + ", <br> Vetro = " + glass[a] + ", <br> Carta = " + paper[a] + "</li>");
    })

    const resultMetal = data.sort((a, b) => b.metalValue - a.metalValue)[0];
    const resultGlass = data.sort((a, b) => b.glassValue - a.glassValue)[0];
    const resultPaper = data.sort((a, b) => b.paperValue - a.paperValue)[0];
    const resultPlastic = data.sort((a, b) => b.plasticValue - a.plasticValue)[0];

    $("#metal p").html("Il repod con id "+resultMetal.idValue+"<br>situato in <br>" + resultMetal.addressValue + "<br> ha consumato più metallo con un valore di " + resultMetal.metalValue);
    $("#vetro p").html("Il repod con id "+resultGlass.idValue+"<br>situato in <br>" + resultGlass.addressValue + "<br> ha consumato più vetro con un valore di " + resultGlass.glassValue);
    $("#plastica p").html("Il repod con id "+resultPlastic.idValue+"<br>situato in <br>" + resultPlastic.addressValue + "<br> ha consumato più plastica con un valore di " + resultPlastic.plasticValue);
    $("#carta p").html("Il repod con id "+resultPaper.idValue+"<br>situato in <br>" + resultPaper.addressValue + "<br> ha consumato più carta con un valore di " + resultPaper.paperValue);


  }
```

Comment: The code that checks for overlapping elements works fine.

Comment: @danh that's strange, I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'idValue' of undefined` but

Comment: While your array includes both `e` and `f`, it does **not** include `[e,f]`.

Comment: @PM77-1 yeah it was just an example

Comment: @PM77-1 the code checks for elements of array savePods in ids.

Comment: @danh - Yes. My comment does not apply.

Comment: @rob.m the error indicates one of resultMetal, resultGlass resultPlastic or resultPaper is undefined.

Comment: @danh I must have something in promise then. If I have 5 ids it's ok but if I had a 6th then it won't work. had removed singles ids just to check if any of them had some issues but not. So since I don't have type of limiter like 5 or 6, then something gets wrong after 5 with promise. I'm just guessing, this is driving me mad

Comment: Shouldn't `var savedRepods = <?php echo json_encode($userPostsInternal); ?> ;` already give you JSON? Why `savedRepods.split(",")`?

Comment: @StackSlave yea thougth so too but i don't think it is doing it

Comment: @StackSlave it's giving a plain 33,35,26, 20, 18,24 in console if i console log before the split

Comment: @StackSlave I also did savedRepods = savedRepods.map(i=>i.trim()); just in case

Answer (score 1):

Probably because of array entries are `object` types. `Array.prototype.contains` are not working for object types. Because in js:

```js
var a = {
  prop: 'value'
}

var b = {
  prop: 'value'
}

if (a != b) {
  console.log('a is not equal to b');
}
```

In javascript `=` (equals) operator checks for references are same or not for `object` types. Reference is address of the object in memory. In my first example `a` and `b` has its own different reference so for javascript `a` is not equals to `b`.

Instead of `contains` you can use `some` method which requires a callback to manually check matches. Here's an example using `some` method to find an element is exists or not.

```js
var array = [
  { name: 'Anna', age: 19 },
  { name: 'Sara', age: 17 },
  { name: 'John', age: 21 },
  { name: 'Doe', age: 34 }
]

var john = { name: 'John', age: 21 };

if (array.some((other) => {
  return other.name == john.name && other.age == john.age
})) {
  console.log('John is exists in the array');
}
```

If you don't want to check each property for objects you may check for `JSON.stringfy(other) == JSON.stringfy(john)`.

Comment: thanks but i think the comparison is fine, I must have something in promise. If I have 5 ids it's ok but if I add a 6th then it won't work. I had removed singles ids just to check if any of them had some issues but not. So since I don't have any type of limiter like 5 or 6, then something gets wrong after 5 with promise. I'm just guessing, this is driving me mad.

Comment: maybe this           `for (var i = 0; i < savedRepods.length; i++) {
              for (var a = 0; a < ids.length; a++) {` is giving +1 in promise and that's why is jumping the index and creating the issue?

Comment: @rob.m could you share `console.log(ids)` output?

Comment: console.log(ids) > (51) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51]

Comment: console.log(savedRepods) >  ["33", "35", "26", "20", "18", "24"]

Comment: Ah :D they are not same types.  '33' is not equals to 33 for example

Comment: oh! this is how I am getting them   var array = <?php echo $contents; ?> ;

Comment: write this line before checking .contains  :  `ids = ids.map(id => id.toString())`

Comment: how could I make them the same? This is how I push them       `array.map(function(item) {
          coords.push(item.Lat + "," + item.Lng);
          ids.push(item.ID);
          date.push(item.Date);
          plastic.push(item.Plastic);
          paper.push(item.Paper);
          glass.push(item.Glass);
          metal.push(item.Metal);
      });`

Comment: where exactly sorry?

Comment: before this line: `if(ids.includes(savedRepods[i]) ) {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208887/discussion-between-rob-m-and-misir-jafarov).